# Network Graph D3 nodes collapse

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I have a network graph using D3 and I would like to make nodes expandable/collapsable. Where exactly can I add the collapse feature ?

This is my code to which I need to add collapse to nodes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const links: any = data?.edges;
    const nodes: any = data?.nodes;

    const simulation = forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force(
        'link',
        forceLink(links)
          .id((d: any) => d.id)
          .distance((d: any) => 150 * d.distance)
          .strength(0.1)
      )
      .force('charge', forceManyBody().strength(-400))
      .force('x', forceX(size.width / 2).strength(0.02))
      .force('y', forceY(size.height / 2).strength(0.05));

    const svg = select(svgRef.current as any);

    svg.selectAll('circle').remove();
    svg.selectAll('text').remove();
    svg.selectAll('g').remove();

    
    svg
      .append('defs')
      .selectAll('marker')
      .data(['test'])
      .join('marker')
      .attr('id', (d: string) => `arrow-${d}`)
      .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
      .attr('refX', 15)
      .attr('refY', -0.5)
      .attr('markerWidth', 6)
      .attr('markerHeight', 6)
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .append('path')
      .attr('fill', arrowColor)
      .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5'); */

    const link = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll('path')
      .data(links)
      .join('path')
      .attr('stroke', arrowColor);
    /*     link.attr('marker-end', (d: any) =>
      displayArrow ? `url(${new URL(`#arrow-${'test'}`, window.location.href)})` : ''
    ); */

    const node = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('fill', 'currentColor')
      .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
      .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(nodes)
      .join('g')
      .call(handlingDrag(simulation));

    node.append('circle').attr('fill', nodeColor).attr('stroke', nodeColor).attr('stroke-width', 1.5).attr('r', 4);

    node
      .append('text')
      .attr('x', 8)
      .attr('y', '0.31em')
      .text((d: { id: string }) => d.id)
      .attr('color', fontColor)
      .style('font', textFont)
      .clone(true)
      .lower()
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', textShadowColor)
      .attr('stroke-width', 3)
      .style('font', textFont);

    simulation.on('tick', () => {
      link.attr('d', linkArc);
      node.attr('transform', (d: { x: number; y: number }) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
    });
  }, [data, size, displayArrow]);
```